# Why is the term 'Voltage' used instead of electric potential in "output voltage" within logic gate implementations?

Tags: voltage, logic-gates

[image]

This is a drawing of a MOSFET implementation of a NOT Gate. V_OUT is the voltage that will be output. However, I find the term "voltage" strange, because a point of a circuit shall be "electric potential", not "voltage". voltage means electric potential difference. And therefore in order to get the voltage of something you need two points on a circuit.

So my question is, is the term V_OUT legitimate in this situation?

My guess is that maybe the voltage is calculated by the difference of electric potential of two points: the ground electric potential, and the point labeled as V_OUT. And, merely labeling one point on the circuit V_OUT is a shorthand way of saying that.

Comment: In EE we call it a voltage in relative terms to a ground or 0 volt node.

Comment: The voltage is in reference to ground.  The ground symbol is the horizontal bar at the bottom of your schematic.

Comment: @Andyaka Yay my guess was correct. Thanks

Comment: It’s also an (US) English thing. It’s called tension in many European countries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

V_OUT is legitimate as long as it is clear what represents aka to which point in the circuit it is referenced to.

V_OUT It is used in order to avoid writing "Voltage potential referenced to GND" again and again. It's a symbol to make reading easier.

Answer (score 2):

Your guess is correct. Generally voltages are measured in respect to some chosen 0V potential in the circuit, commonly called ground in digital chips.

Answer (score 2):

Because "voltage" is one two-syllable word, while "electric potential" is two words adding up to six syllables.